# I am Unable to fetch the $form['select'] array in Views Bulk Operations

Tags: views

I am trying to use [vbo_multipage_selection](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/rudiedirkx/2446867) module to Select the Contents Created to Create a newsletter as the Views Bulk Operations currently doesn't support multipage selection.
This module works upon an array called $form['select'] which I think, stores the id of checkboxes / content selected by the user and is generated by **Views Bulk Operations** module after the user selects the contents but its not being generated, Are there any dependency issues or Is there any other way to use multipage selection.